# Calling API and Updating a Map frequently

Tags: java, api

I am getting data from an API and storing the data into a map. The limitation is that I want to call the API once, then I have a loop over the API response and store the data into a map.
What I have done so far is:

```
public void callAPIFunction(String id){
   // here I am calling the API and saving the model response.
}

public Map<String, String> UpdateDataMaps(String project_id){
   // here I have a loop over the API response (callAPIFunction method's output)
}
```

After all these I am going to have multiple functions that is for extracting data from the maps. So the functions are using the UpdateDataMaps method's output.

I think something here is missing to connect these functions together. In this approach, I have to call the methods one by one, or maybe I should do something to run callAPIFunction and UpdateDataMaps functions frequently depending on the limitations of the API that I have, because it is a third-party API and I have some limitations.

My question is: is there any other approach that I can use to connect these methods and update my map values? Or is my approach efficient? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Does the third party have any api which accepts multiple ids and return a list of model responses? If so that would be the best approach.
Otherwise, if `UpdateDataMaps` has to deal with multiple `project_id` you should pass list of project_ids in `UpdateDataMap`s method and for each ID, call the api and update the map and the proceed on calling the other methods.

Comment: I find it hard to follow your explanation with the little code you've provided. So `callAPIFunction(id)` calls some things and then `UpdateDataMaps(project_id)` too? How are `id` and `project_id` related? What data do you get? What and where do you want to store that information? Is the API endpoint a singleton or how are you sharing data between instances?

Comment: @Thomas assume that `id` is something like user_id and project_id is the projects of the user.